# Jasmin unit test code inside click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jasmine, click

I have the following code to test:

```
function mainFunction() {
    $("#testButton").on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            success: function () {
            console.log("button clicked");
            }   
        }); 
}
$(document).ready(mainFunction());
```

The jasmine test for this code thus far:

```
describe("when button is clicked", function () {
    it("will say 'button clicked'", function () {        
        $('#testButton').trigger('click');
        .
        .
        .
      /* expect results from mocking $.ajax within */
        .
        .
        .
    });
});
```

The related fixture:

```
<input type="button" id="testButton" value="Create snapshot" 
onclick="mainFunction()"/>
```

I'm trying to test the ajax inside but I can't get the click function to fire to allow me to do so.  What am I missing here?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note: `$(document).ready(mainFunction());` is immediately executing the mainFunction, possibly before the document is actually ready.  If you only want the method to happen once the document is ready, remove the `()` from the function call.

Comment: You also do not want, nor need, that onclick inline binding.  Every time you click that button, it's going to create a new, duplicate, event handler on the button.

Comment: Fix those two things and see if your jasmine tests behaves differently with the properly bound event handler at the correct time.

Comment: I made those two changes and still no go.  But then I realized that I forgot to load the fixtures!!!  It now works as expected.     beforeEach( function() { 
        loadFixtures("test2.html");
    });